# delete item in dictionary one level down

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
{"python":[
  {"name":"achname","points":9999, "description":"The best achievement ever"}
]}
```

I want to delete the achievement `achname` from the list - but I don't know the category name(`python`). The achievement will always be one level down, but maybe in a different category other that python. How can I do this?

Comment: You will have to search through all keys in the outer dictionary, then through each list value until you find one with the right name. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html for working with dicts and lists.

Answer (score 0):

What about using del, and the .keys() method?  I don't know how your dictionary is going to be structured, but assuming that "name" will always refer to the achievement you want to delete:

```
for key in foo.keys():
    if "name" in foo[key]:
        del foo[key]["name"]
```

Unfortunately, you will need to iterate over every top-level element in the dictionary, to search through all the sub dictionaries.